# Displaying The Individual Random Numbers And The Sum Of A Python Array

Tags: python, arrays, random

What logic would you use to display the randomly generated numbers of an array, while simultaneously printing out the sum of said random numbers? This was for an assignment and it was supposed to be done with a few functions, similar to how I have it set up.

I've been able to display the random numbers in the array, but when I try to sum them it calls the function again and gives me the sum of a new set of randomly generated numbers. I've reset the code a bit as that chunk of code didn't really help me.

```
import random
import math

def fillList(count):
    list = []
    for i in range(0, count):
        list.append(random.randint(0, 10))
    return list

def sumList(val):
    total = 0
    for i in val:
        total = total + val
        total += total
    return total

def printList(lst):
    for val in lst:
        print(val)
        sum = sumList(val)
    return sum

myList = fillList(25)
printList(myList)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this out:

> Solution 1:

```
import random
import math

def fillList(count):
    list = []
    for i in range(0, count):
        list.append(random.randint(0, 10))
    return list

def sumList(val,total):
    total += val
    return total

def printList(lst):
    total = 0
    for val in lst:
        print(val)
        total = sumList(val,total)
    return total

myList = fillList(25)
res = printList(myList)
```

**Note: Never use python keywords(sum, dict etc.) to define variable names.**

> Solution 2:

```
import random
import math

def fillList(count):
    list = []
    for i in range(0, count):
        list.append(random.randint(0, 10))
    return list

def sumList(lst):
    total = 0
    for val in lst:
        total += val
    return total

def printList(lst):
    [print(val) for val in lst]
    sumValue = sumList(lst)
    return sumValue

myList = fillList(25)
res = printList(myList)
```

Comment: Thank you man, I was researching all over the place but sometimes something doesn't click until you see it done.

Comment: Welcome and also remember this always Never use keywords like sum, dict etc. to define variable names.

Answer (score -1):

If you want your `printList` to give the total, you may call it outside the loop and by given it the whole list like this

```
def sumList(lst):  # return sum(lst)
    total = 0
    for val in lst:
        total += val
    return total

def printList(lst):
    for val in lst:
        print(val)
    total = sumList(lst)
    print("Total is", total)
```

And use as

```
myList = fillList(5)
print(myList)  # [4, 7, 7, 2, 7]
printList(myList)  # prints every value on a new line

4
7
7
2
7
Total is 27
```

Comment: Yeah I had an idea of how to do it in two functions, but the assignment was asking for three, and that's where I was getting rather confused. I appreciate the help nonetheless however.

Comment: @AbsolutelyNoLogic you have your 3 functions here, I just didn't paste the fillList as I changed nothing